# Authentication using OAuth and uploading videos to youtube in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I want to upload video to youtube using API. Further i am using OAuth2 authentication to authenticate user but i am unable to figure out where i am going wrong.

I would like to mention here that right now i am testing it on my localhost so my redirect url is localhost and i have no consumer_key and consumer_secret but i am using HMAC-SHA1 signature method (for unregistered domain) but here i have no parameter option to provide the signature method

Can anyone please help me in getting the right thing out of it ? Here is the following code which i have wrote :

```
    Dim CONSUMER_KEY As String = "anonymous"
    Dim CONSUMER_SECRET As String = "anonymous"
    Dim SCOPE As String = "https://gdata.youtube.com"

    Dim parameters As OAuth2Parameters = New OAuth2Parameters
    With parameters
        .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("ClientID").ToString
        .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("ClientSecret").ToString
        .Scope = SCOPE
        .RedirectUri = "http://localhost:13332/Default.aspx"
    End With

    Dim authorizationUrl As String = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters)
    Dim AccessCode As String = authorizationUrl
    parameters.AccessCode = AccessCode
    OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters)  ' **HERE I GOT ERROR ERROR AS The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

    Dim developerKey As String
    developerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("developerKey").ToString
    Dim settings As YouTubeRequestSettings = New YouTubeRequestSettings("MyApp", developerKey, "AuthSubToken(I don't have it)")
    Dim request As YouTubeRequest = New YouTubeRequest(settings)

    'UPLOAD YOUTUBE VIDEO METADATA
    Dim NewVideo As New Video
    NeWvideo.Title = "My Test Movie"
    NeWvideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    NeWvideo.Keywords = "cars, funny"
    NeWvideo.Description = "My description"
    NeWvideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    NeWvideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema))
    'NeWvideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = New GeoRssWhere(37, -122)

    Dim FormUploadToken As FormUploadToken = request.CreateFormUploadToken(NeWvideo)
    Dim UploadUrl As String = FormUploadToken.Url
    Dim UploadToken As String = FormUploadToken.Token

    Session("posturl") = UploadUrl
    Session("posttoken") = UploadToken
```

Also i am not been able to get the process to redirect user to google login page to authenticate himself and grant access permission to my web application.

Here again my requirement is to upload video to youtube using browser-based-uploading to specific user account and not to a single account and that to using OAuth2 authetication process.

Please help me in figuring out the error and provide me solution here ?
Thanks in advance.